# URI issue after attempting to run Rails server with completely new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the following errors directly after creating a new (untouched) Rails app.

```
Error: uninitialized constant URI::Generic,
NameError: uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI
```

Where exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know exactly what could cause this, BUT updating my ruby version from 2.5.0 to 2.6.5 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom in a different scenario. After updating a Bundler version in Dockerfile (1.7 -> 2.1), I got this error in Jenkins, whereas the error did not occur locally:

```
[2020-03-31T12:40:05.694Z] + bundle exec rake setup:test
[2020-03-31T12:40:06.702Z] rake aborted!
[2020-03-31T12:40:06.702Z] NameError: uninitialized constant URI::Generic
```

I'm not sure the exact cause of the error, but for me, the fix was to require `uri` at the top of `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'uri'
```

Comment: This is not working for Ruby-3.1.2 , can you please let me know any other option?

Comment: Sorry, no...I don't have anything else to suggest. If you find another solution, please add it as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar Same for me.  Did you get past it?

Comment: @codenoob, Yes I solved with use bundle update.

Comment: Thanks @rakesh Kumar. I got past it as well, but not with a simple bundle update. Instead, I think I moved to a newer ruby version.

Comment: OK, it popped up again. The issue was ruby-growl. Clearly not vital.  Removed the gem and all is good.  Growal may be it will be fixed later, or maybe ruby-growl is done now.